# How to reference a resource file

Tags: java

I have two exe's that I want to reference once I build the package into a JAR. My structure looks like the following:

Project

1. build
2. dist
3. nbproject
4. src

   - myProject

     - Main.java
   - resources

     - 1.exe
     - 2.exe

How can I get the file paths of 1.exe and 2.exe from Main.java? Will this still work once I build the JAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you build your jar you can use META-INF/mainfest file to reference all the required resources you need for your jar file

Comment: put your resource folder in the META-INF and then reference the jar you need in the .mf file

Comment: So I see the META-INF folder in the libraries/jdk 1.8/resources.jar/ directory. Is that where I am putting the folder? Then what would I put in the .mf file? Also, how do I then reference those files in my code? Sorry, this is new to me.

Comment: for example you can do some thing like this in java code to get resources in meta-inf InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/system.properties");